# JavaFX "Enter" and "Tab" events

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, javafx-2

Pressing on the <kbd>Enter</kbd> button is similar to mouse left click on focused node and pressing on <kbd>Tab</kbd> changes focused node. How can I disable it? I just want that these pressings do nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to `installEventHandler` create under `public void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel)`, it will work for you

```
public void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
//.............
//............. your code
installEventHandler(scene);
}
```

then into `installEventHandler(final Scene keyNode)` method

```
final EventHandler<javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent> keyEventHandler = new EventHandler<javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent>() {
      public void handle(final javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
    //do nothing
    }
    if (keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB) {
    //Do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: What is installEventHandler?

Comment: Thanks, but instead "//do nothink" was need to change action.consume

Comment: A customs method to handle your events... @ Biy